# WebClient maxConnection pool and pendingAcquireMaxCount limit?

Tags: netty, connection-pooling, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

Lets imagine I need a netty server(reactive/non blocking), and I need to process at maximum 50 http requests at the same time. But I now that these requests have to use a WebClient(netty reactive http client), that has a pool of maxConnections of 16, and 32 as pendingAcquireMaxCount (https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_connection_pool). The "problem" now is the next: if you limit this pendingAcquireMaxCount of the WebClient to some number or leave the default,

- how you modify the maxConnections and pendingAcquireMaxCount parameters of this webclient in order to avoid errors like `"reactor.netty.internal.shaded.reactor.pool.PoolAcquirePendingLimitException: Pending acquire queue has reached its maximum size of 32"`?. Because if I am not wrong, when a thread uses this webclient, because of this webclient is non blocking, the thread goes back to the thread pool before the http request is done and this thread process other request taking other http connection from the WebClient pool. This is why I see it complicated to calculate these configurations without getting an error like the mentioned one.

Thanks

Comment: Configuring max connections and pending acquire max count is not a trivial task and depends a lot on the solution. I would recommend you to measure your solution with various configurations and to see how it will behave.